# Mongoid error in heroku: Database should be a Mongo::DB, not a nil class

Tags: ruby, heroku, sinatra, mongoid

I have a Sinatra app on heroku and it keeps crashing due to this error:

`app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mongoid-1.2.14/lib/mongoid/config.rb:52 in 'master': Database should be a Mongo::DB, not a nil class`

I set up Mongoid 3.x according to the heroku instructions, and the app works on my local machine, so I'm not sure what's causing this problem. My gemfile looks like this:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
ruby "1.9.3"

gem 'sinatra'
gem 'mongo'
gem 'mongoid'
gem 'bson_ext'
gem 'json'
gem 'nokogiri'
gem 'aws-s3', '0.6.2', :require => 'aws/s3'
gem 'sinatra-reloader'
gem 'debugger'
gem 'thin'
```

Here's my `mongoid.yml`:

```
development:
  sessions:
    default:
      database: db
      hosts:
        - localhost:27017
production:
  sessions:
    default:
      uri: <%= ENV['MONGOHQ_URL'] %>
      options:
        skip_version_check: true
        safe: true
```

And here's my app file:

```
require 'bundler/setup'
require 'sinatra'
require 'json'
require 'mongo'
require 'mongoid'

Mongoid.load!('mongoid.yml', :production)
def get_connection
  return @db_connection if @db_connection
  db = URI.parse(ENV['MONGOHQ_URL'])
  db_name = db.path.gsub(/^\//, '')
  @db_connection = Mongo::Connection.new(db.host, db.port).db(db_name)
  @db_connection.authenticate(db.user, db.password) unless (db.user.nil? || db.user.nil?)
  @db_connection
end

db = get_connection

class Model1
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :name, :type => String

end
```

I shouldn't have to specify a database name since I'm using the uri field, so I'm not sure why the database if nil?